# Can you write a Turing machine in set theory?

Tags: set-theory, turing-machines

Let $T$ be a Turing Machine. Let us define $S$ as the set containing the result of the turing machine calculation. Then presumably this is expressable in terms of ZFC set theory. Since the result of a calculation is just a (or pair) binary number(s) which can be represented as some set.

But what would this set be if the Turing machine never stopped?

Would the set be ill-defined? Hence this leaves me to believe that expressing a Turing machine in (typed) set theory is forbidden?

Comment: I would start by noticing you have not used any actual properties of set theory. Let's do arithmetic instead:  define $n$ as the result of the TM calculation. What would this number be if the TM doesn't halt? Would this number be undefined? Is arithmetic unsuitable for discussing Turing machines?

Comment: Well you can't define a Turing machine with just arithmetic. You would at least need a definition of functions.

Comment: Yes, you can define Turing machines in arithmetic. But that's not really my point. My point is that you can replace set theory with literally anything here. You are essentially saying that because the attempted definition you wrote down isn't actually a definition, that somehow your system is incapable of writing definitions.

Comment: Are you saying that you can have a Turing machine T and an input Q and using arithmetic of multiplying them together (for example) you get the output. O=T*Q. This would be impossible because the halting problem would be solved. If you mean arithmetic in terms of algorithms, then this is arithmetic + algorithms. The algorithm part might be expressed outside arithmetic.

Comment: No... I wasn't intending to say much about arithmetic at all, only trying to point out the absurdity of what you were arguing in the question. But anyway, by arithmetic, I mean expressible in first order logic in terms of natural number addition, multiplication, etc. All algorithms are expressible in arithmetic in this sense (if you believe the Church-Turing thesis): in fact, a function is recursive if and only if it is representable in PA (in the sense that there is a formula $\phi(x,y)$ such that if $f(x)=y$ PA proves $\phi(x,y)$ and if not then PA proves $\lnot\phi(x,y)$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the Turing machine calculation might not terminate, then the set containing the result is indeed not defined. But that's no fault of set theory (on the contrary, things are working exactly as they should be), nor is it any indication that set theory is somehow unable to formalize the idea of turing machines.

When you write down a definition, it is incumbent on you to show that it is actually a definition. "Let $x=12$ if the Goldbach conjecture is true" cannot be shown to be a valid definition since we don't know if the Goldbach conjecture is true. "Let $x=12$ if the Goldbach conjecture is True, otherwise let $x=10$", is a valid definition regardless cause we've covered both options. Similarly, "let $x$ be the output of the 147th turing machine on input 5" is not necessarily a definition unless we know that the 147th turing machine halts on input 5. If we don't, we better say what $x$ is in the event that it doesn't halt.

(It might be easier to see this if we try to define a function instead. Let $f(n)=0$ if $n$ can be written as the sum of two squares. This is not a definition of a (total) function cause we haven't said what happens if $n$ is not the sum of two squares. This doesn't mean set theory, or arithmetic, or whatever, is incapable of handling numbers.)

Nothing changes in the situtation where we say "let $S$ be the singleton set containing the output of the 147th Turing machine on input 5"... this simply is not necessarily a definition.

Turing machines can certainly be defined in set theory. You can define the internal state they are in and the location of the tape head as simple recursive functions. You can express things like "at computational step $n,$ the turing machine is in state $i$" as sentences in the language of set theory. You can express "the turing machine halts with output $m$" as "there is an $n$ such that at step $n$, the turing machine is in one of its halting state, and the output tape at this time contains the number $m$". You can express anything you want about a given turing machine on a given input, or about all turing machines, on all inputs, or whatever.

And there is nothing inherently set theoretical about it either: all these things can be encoded (perhaps somewhat less elegantly) as numbers and then you can talk about Turing machines in the language of arithmetic. You can prove more things in ZFC than in PA (for instance, there is a TM that halts if and only if PA is inconsistent... this can be proven to not halt in ZFC but not in PA), but the 'natural arena' for formalizing the mathematics of Turing machines is in arithemetic, not set theory.

Comment: Ah, I see. So if $H(T,n)$ means the the Turing machine $T$ terminates in $n$ steps, then we would say something like $(x=\{3\} )\land \exists n:H(T,n) \lor (x=\{4\})$

Comment: @zooby You're going for "$x=\{3\}$ if machine T halts, $x=\{4\}$ otherwise" and that would be a valid definition. In order to write down a formula uniquely satisfied by this set, you would need to put "$\lnot\exists n H(T,n)$" in the second clause as well... as it stands $\{4\}$ always satisfies this formula which is not what is intended.